# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "authentifizieren" und "authentisieren"?

Tags: difference, verb, word-usage

Es gibt die beiden Verben *authentifizieren* und *authentisieren*, die beide mit dem Begriff *"authentisch"* verwandt sind. In Dokumenten bestimmter Fachbereiche, zum Beispiel in der EDV, findet man beide Begriffe. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob sie immer korrekt verwendet werden.

Sind die beiden **Synonyme oder gibt es einen Unterschied** in der Bedeutung und in ihrem Verwendungszweck?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter sind keineswegs Synonyme, auch wenn sie ähnlich klingen und wohl auch nicht immer richtig eingesetzt werden.

[*"Authentisieren"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/authentisieren) ist ein Fachbegriff aus der Rechtssprache und bedeutet, einen Sachverhalt rechtsgültig zu machen.

[*"Authentifizieren"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/authentifizieren) wird auch in anderen Bereichen angewandt, wenn die Echtheit eines Sachverhalts bezeugt wird. Ein Beispiel verdeutlicht vielleicht den Unterschied:

> Der Notar **authentifiziert** die Echtheit einer Urkunde und **authentisiert** sich dabei mit seiner Unterschrift und seinem Dienstsiegel.
>
> Der Bankkunde **authentisiert** sich am Bankautomat mit seiner Geheimnummer. Wenn diese stimmt, dann **authentifiziert** der Bankautomat den Kunden (als echt) und gibt die Geldscheine aus.

[In der EDV](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Authentisieren-authentifizieren.png) werden beide Begriffe verwendet:

> Der Benutzer authentisiert sich am Server mit seinem Passwort. Nur wenn der Benutzer dem System bekannt ist, wird der Benutzer vom Server authentifiziert (also als gültiger Benutzer erkannt).

Comment: Sehr interessant! Heisst es auch wirklich "Der Bankkunde authentisiert sich am Bankautomaten mit seiner Geheimnummer"? Rechtsgueltig macht er sich ja nicht, oder?

Comment: von https://www.datenschutzbeauftragter-info.de/authentisierung-authentifizierung-und-autorisierung/ :

Authentisierung - Nachweis einer Person - Vorzeigen Personalausweis
Authentifizierung - Prüfung der behaupteten Authentisierung - Bestätigung durch Türsteher
Autorisierung - Einräumung von speziellen Rechten - kostenfreie Getränke